# Android Google Maps v2 clickable marker title

Tags: java, android, google-maps, maps

I have a Google map on my app. The markers are already clickable, but I'm looking for a way to make the title's clickable to do an action (like going to a places "description" page). Here is what I mean

[image: http://i.imgur.com/ndwOjx9.png?1]

```
    public class MapFragment extends Fragment {

    private GoogleMap map;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_map, container,
                false);

        String myTag = getTag();
        ((PlacesAndMapActivity) getActivity()).setTabFragmentMap(myTag);


        map = ((SupportMapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(
                R.id.map)).getMap();

        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(34.039407, -118.254763))
                .title("Restaurant 1"));

        return rootView;
    }
    }
```

Anyway I can make the title clickable? Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You want to use [GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener.html)

Class Overview
Callback interface for click/tap events on a marker's info window.

```
public abstract void onInfoWindowClick (Marker marker)
```

Called when the marker's info window is clicked.